# Why am I getting "1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims" when working with 2 deployments

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to do a fairly simple red/green setup using Minikube where I want 1 pod running a red container and 1 pod running a green container and a service to hit each. To do this my k82 file is like...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: main-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/Users/jackiegleason/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: main-volume-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: express-app
  name: express-service-red
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: express-app-red
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: express-app
  name: express-service-green
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: express-app-green
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-app-deployment-red
  labels:
    app: express-app-red
    tier: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: express-app-red
        tier: app
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: express-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: main-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: express-app-container
          image: partyk1d24/hello-express:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/external"
              name: express-app-storage
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
              name: express-endpnt
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-app-deployment-green
  labels:
    app: express-app-green
    tier: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: express-app-green
        tier: app
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: express-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: main-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: express-app-container
          image: partyk1d24/hello-express:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: DEPLOY_TYPE
              value: "Green"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/external"
              name: express-app-storage
          ports:
              - containerPort: 3000
                protocol: TCP
                name: express-endpnt
```

But when I run I get...

> 0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

What am I missing? It worked fine without the second deployment so what am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: The documentation and other SO questions are a little unclear here, but it looks like a `ReadWriteOnce` PVC can only be used by one pod at a time.  The pattern you have here has some scalability problems (it prevents you from ever using more than one node); can you restructure the application so the two deployments don't need to share files?

Comment: I really don't want to but I can for testing just to confirm. So I commented out the Volume info for the green deployment and now green starts but red fails still w/ same prob

Comment: BTW the file that both are writing to is a log file. I would like the log files in the same folder (Volume) but if there is a better way I am open to it

Comment: Also if I comment out all volumes then it works fine

Comment: It might be easier to not write logs as files, but instead let them go to the process's stdout.  `kubectl logs` could retrieve them, and [you can configure a log collector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-node-logging-agent) to send them somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same a PV with `accessMode: ReadWriteOnce` multiple times.

To do this you would need to use a volume that supports ReadWriteMany access mode.
Check out k8s documentation for [the list of Volume Plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) that support this feature.

Additionally, as David already menioned, it's much better to log to the STDOUT.

You can also check solutions like [FluentBit](https://fluentbit.io/)/[fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) or [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack).